# How to add people with the new YouTube profiles as friends?

Tags: youtube

It's easy to add people with the old YouTube profiles as friend, as you just click the link:

[image]

I see no such option where the other links are on the new profiles though:

[image]

Is there still a way to do that, or did they just remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They [seem](http://www.google.co.nz/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=59ca2574e136bc6a&hl=en) to have removed the button, but there is a workaround.

Copy the *username* of the person you want to add as a friend (just under *Created by*; 'GamingSE' in your example), and then go to your **Inbox > Address Book**. Click on **New > Contact...** and type in the *username* inside the **Username** box on the right pane. Now click **Save**, select that user, click **Add to Friends** on the above bar and you're done. This is the only way to add someone as a friend at the moment.

Comment: Well, then you have to click the "Add to Friends" button, but nice find. :)

Comment: Exactly :) Edited my answer for the tiny missing part.